# How to make the Adaptec AHA-2940 SCSI PCI card work with Ubuntu?

Tags: scsi

My AHA-2940 shows up via `lspci` but none of the connected drives show up in `lsblk`. What do I need to do to make my system recognize these drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/etc/default/grub` edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` so that it reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pci-assign-busses"` then run the command `sudo update-grub` and restart.

Comment: Having the same issue. AHA-2940W not been detected. When I add the linux option mentioned above I get kernel panics on boot.  The panics stop if I remove the AHA-2940W card. The card is working in another system running Paladin (Ubuntu).  So I don;t suspect the card.